# How to create instance of javascript object on the basic of Object name

Tags: javascript, object

I have 3 js file.

object.js constains following object,

```
function User()
{
 //Some property
}

function Employee()
{
 // Some Property
}
```

.. etc.

and There Framework.js in which we need to create a method CreateInstance(objectname).

we need to create this method in a such a way that one who will use createinstance method will just need to pass objectname whose instance he needs. So in future if any object is added in object.js, createinstance should be able to create instance of that object on the basis of ObjectName without  modifying CreateInstance method.

```
function CreateInstance(objectName)
  {
  //logic for creating instance of object.
  }
```

Is it Possible and How?

Comment: `new window[objectName]()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an instance by providing a string (that is how I interpret your question) you can always use `eval`:

```
function CreateInstance(objectName) {
    return eval("new " + objectName + "()");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One legitemate use of `eval`.

```
function CreateInstance(objectName) {
  return new (eval(objectName))();
}
```

You may add some validation to make sure that `objectName` is a word and `eval(objectName)` is a function if you want to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work as long as User and Employee are defined at the window scope:

```
function CreateInstance(objectName)
{
    if (typeof window[objectName] == 'function') {
        return new window[name];
    }

    // return null or throw an error ...
}

var user = CreateInstance('User');
console.log(user instanceof User); // true

var employee = CreateInstance('Employee');
console.log(employee instanceof Employee); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `new` operator? You can use that currently like this:

```
var user = new User();

alert(user instanceof User); // Shows "true"
```

Comment: Thanks..but this does not solve my issue. I need to create instance of "ObjectName".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to have something like Factory Pattern.
There are Different ways of doing it.But as per above statement given it seems you are going bit wrong.

Javascript is a function based language where a function represents a object itself (In other terms a class like structure).

> **Once you write a function you have already created an object.**

You can always create a object using new keyword.

Reason for directly using new keyword is "Its a Global Considered Lang." i.e. you can access an object globally from anywhere if it refered anytime within a system

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (and shouldn't use) `eval` for this.

```
var myconstructors = {
    User: function(){/*...*/},
    Employee: function(){/*...*/}
};

var createinstance = function(name){
    return new myconstructors[name]();
};
```